# checkmarx cannot see the code in static method

Tags: java, checkmarx, secure-coding, log-forging

Checkmarx does not understand static method.

```
String journeyId = request.getHeader("JOURNEY_ID");
journeyId = LogUtils.getUserInputText(journeyId);
LOGGER.info("journeyId=" + journeyId);
```

For the code above, **Checkmarx** always complains there is *Log Forging* because it thought `journeyId` is from user input. But the `LogUtils.getUserInputText` only allows return ascii text. But **Checkmarx** does not recognize that.
Then I did this test

```
String myJourneyId1 = request.getHeader("JOURNEY_ID");
LogUtils logUtils = new LogUtils();
myJourneyId1 = logUtils.getUserInputText(myJourneyId1);
LOGGER.info("myJoruneyId1=" + myJourneyId1);
```

I did not change anything on `LogUtils`. I only instance it before I call the static method and now **Checkmarx** does not complain anymore.

Here is the getUserInputText

```
public static String getUserInputText(final String input) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(input)) {
            return "";
        }
        
        return input.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7E]", "\\uFFFD");
    }
```

It does not matter what is inside the getUserInputText. Checkmarx complains the first one but not the second one. They are calling the same function.

To be honest, I am quite frustrated on this. It wasted my whole afternoon to test why my fix did not solve the log forging issue. And eventually I found it was a checkmarx issue.

---

More interesting findings here:
If I move the LogUtils class to another dependency project, Checkmarx always complains log forging issue no matter I instance it or not.

Comment: Can you share the `getUserInputText`methos? Can you add a language tag? Can you keep this question professional and not a bug report?

Comment: Post the `LogUtil() {...}` constructor.

Comment: here you are.  It is an empty one. 
public LogUtils() {
    }

Comment: Please also check this! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62545939/how-to-fix-checkmarx-trust-boundary-violation